# Having an issue updating label text while using multiple forms

Tags: c#

On form 1 I have a label called item1, and on form 2 I want to click a button that changes the text of the label, but currently having trouble doing so.

I have this on form 1

```
        public string item1text
    {
        get { return this.item1.Text; }
        set { this.item1.Text = value; }
    }
```

and this on form 2 when the button is clicked

```
form1 frm = new form1();

frm.item1text = "hello";
```

Which should work, but it isn't updating the text on form 1 and only showing the original text and not "hello". I'm hiding form 1 while having form 2 up and then re-showing form 1 when form 2 is closed, could this have something to do with messing up showing "hello" ? I've tried refresh(); but no luck.

Comment: How form1 and form2 are related ? Form1 opens form2 or the other way ?

Comment: The code you showed above is perfectly alright but the way you show forms is problem

Comment: form 1 has a button to open form 2 but then hides form 1, then form 2 has a close button that then shows form 1 again

Comment: I'm not convinced we really need yet another version of the "I want to modify an existing form, but create a new one instead" question. See the marked duplicates for just a small sampling of all of the existing questions asking the same thing.

Comment: i would say mine is different from these due to the hiding and showing of forms, all these "duplicates" do not cover that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new form1 in form2, which won't update the existing one. Create a property in form2

```
public Form ParentForm { get; set; }
```

Then in form1 button click set the value

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ParentForm = this;
f2.Show();
this.Hide();
```

in form2 set label text as below

```
ParentForm.item1Text = "Hello";
```